# What is the Difference Between VW 8X0951253 (650) and 8X0951253A (655) Relays?

Tags: vw, relay, passat

What is the difference between the 8X0951253 (650) and 8X0951253A (655) VW Relays?
Original 2012 VW Passat, these (wiper) relays are `Blue`, have the part number `8X09512531 and top marking` 650`. Seems like these are hard to find now days, but the 8X0951253A (655) is marked as a Supersession of the 8X0951253 ([on the VW Parts site](https://parts.vw.com/p/64723132/8x0951253.html)):

[image]
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't know for sure, but it appears from the description they should be interchangeable.

Comment: Upward compatible, anyway. Newest cars may not like OP's older part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If VW is showing the older part (650 I think from your question) as being superseded by the 655 part, then they are interchangeable for YOUR vehicle that uses the 650.

It's possible that they needed a slightly better specification for a newer model vehicle and had the manufacturer change something but since it's a better spec, it will work for the older 650 application.

You really don't know since they don't publish the data sheets most of the time.  But VW only wants to stock the minimum number of spare parts so the 650 is history and all applications use the 655 going forward.